# How do I install Brave Browser if my key is expired and won't update?

Tags: repository, keyserver

I am not able to install Brave Browser and cannot seem to fix it.

```
W: GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com cosmic 
InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 4FE13824E3FFC656 Brave Software <support@brave.com>
E: The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com cosmic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I tried `sudo apt-key list | grep expired`
and got:

```
pub   rsa4096 2018-10-15 [SC] [expired: 2019-04-13]
uid           [ expired] Brave Software <support@brave.com>
```

I did `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 4FE13824E3FFC656` and got:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.1CQeA81kHh/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 4FE13824E3FFC656
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

Now I am stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using cosmic?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, I am. 18.10

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ubuntu 16.04 or higher you can install brave using snap store.
Open your terminal and type `sudo snap install brave` then enter.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to get the latest stable release which snap does not provide.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4FE13824E3FFC656`

Answer (score 0):

you can add apt-key under brave-key server

```
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com --recv-keys <your missing public key>
```